# Qt application release exe not running

Tags: c++, qt

I have built a very simple calculator in Qt. When I run it in release mode from qt creator, everything works fine. However when I go to the release folder and run it, it gives QT5Core.dll, QT5Widgets.dll and QT5Gui.dll not found. After running windeployqt there by:

```
windeployqt .
```

All the dll get added. However, it then gives error VCRUNTIME140_APP.dll and MSVCP140_APP.dll not found. After copying them to the folder. The exe doesn't give any error on double clicking but just does not start. What should I do?
I found this solution [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/97133/problem-deploying-a-simple-qml-windows-app), however I cannot find any qml file in the application directory.

I created it as a QT widget application. I am using Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2017 and MSVC2017 64bit desktop kit. The application is in C++.

**Update:**
Running the command

```
windeployqt Calculator.exe
```

after adding qt to the path seems to do the trick. Application working even after removing qt from the path. Will try running the app inside vm just to be extra sure.

Comment: You say: *however I can not find any qml file in the application directory*, If you are using a .qrc it is no longer necessary to use the .qml since these are embedded in the executable

Comment: Run your application from the command prompt and check if it displays an error message.

Comment: Maybe you can just build the exe with the dependencies?

Comment: Note that Windows, in its wisdom, won’t show the stdout output of a GUI application in the command prompt.  If you want to see stdout you have to eg call AllocConsole() and freopen() to get a window to appear with the stdout output in it.

Answer (score 1):

When running from the command line, add your Qt Bin directory to the PATH. For example:

`C:\> PATH=C:\Qt\Qt5.11.0\5.11.0\msvc2017_64\bin;%PATH%`

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the problem as selbie described it. An another way is to copy the missing .dll-Files to the folder where the.exe is placed.

See here https://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/windows-deployment.html#creating-the-application-package :

> To deploy the application, we must make sure that we copy the relevant Qt DLLs (corresponding to the Qt modules used in the application) and the Windows platform plugin, qwindows.dll, as well as the executable to the same directory tree in the release subdirectory.

Answer (score 1):

set variable VCINSTALLDIR, example:

```
set VCINSTALLDIR=p:\Programs\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\
```

and next run

```
windeployqt.exe app.exe
```

Or copy `vc_redist.x64.exe` from Redist subfolder into folder with your application.

Answer (score 1):

> As @mosa mentioned, To deploy the application, we must make sure that we copy the relevant Qt DLLs (corresponding to the Qt modules used in the application) and the Windows platform plugin, qwindows.dll, as well as the executable to the same directory tree in the release subdirectory.

To add missing `.dll` files first open QT MSVC Console and type `windeployqt.exe` command,

[image]

Then you have to go to the directory which `.exe` file contains. Let's assume my .exe is in the desktop,

```
C:/
cd user/indrajith/desktop
```

Then you can add missing .dll files using following command,

```
 windeployqt.exe --quick.
```

Finally, just double click your `.exe` file to run the program.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Solution:

- Copy "bin" and "plugins" folders from the qt setup directory(C:\Qt\6.2.4\mingw_64) to your release folder.
- Put your .exe file inside that "bin" folder and done.

Now, your .exe application should run.The bin and plugin folders contain required .dll files and unnecessary files can be removed manually.